# regex not to match certain characters

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation

```
(=606.{2})([123|]{2})
```

matches

```
=606  1|
```

but how could i make it match only the not matching cases?
for instance, i need to find a case like the following:

```
=606  4|
```

I tried but no match:

```
(=606.{2})([^123|]{2})
```

All strings have the following pattern:

```
=\d\d\d\s\s..
```

i need to validate the .. characters, which may take the following values:
`1,2,3,|`.

So i need a regex, that would match all these strings that do not apply to the above rule

Also tried 
`^(?!=606.{2}[123|]{2})`, and it does not match also

`=606  4|`

I test here
http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: What is the task you have? Match a string that does not fully match some pattern? `^(?!=606.{2}[123|]{2})`?

Comment: Does all your data start with `=606` and end with `|` and is there always 2 spaces between 606 and the last two characters?

Comment: Try `(=606.{2})(?![123|]{2})(..)`, does it work?

Comment: (=606.{2})(?![123|]{2})(..) worked, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict the last two chars of your expected matches, you may use a lookahead and consume those chars using `..`:

```
(=606.{2})(?![123|]{2})(..)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This matches

- `(=606.{2})` - Group 1: `=606` and 2 chars other than newlines
- `(?![123|]{2})` - next two chars cannot be `1`, `2`, `3` or `|`
- `(..)` - Group 2: any 2 chars other than newline chars.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3D606.%7B2%7D%29%28%3F!%5B123%7C%5D%7B2%7D%29%28..%29&i=%3D606%20%201%7C%0D%0A%3D606%20%204%7C).